# Differential equation with infinite initial value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, infinity, initial-value-problems

I know that given an initial value problem
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(x) &=& G(x,f(x)) \\
f(0) &=& c
\end{eqnarray}
there is a unique solution for $f$ for any sufficiently nice $G$ (in this case Lipschitz continuous is sufficient). What happens if we have a similar situation but with the initial value $f(0) = \infty$? For example, if $G(x,f(x)) = - f(x)^2$, one finds that the solutions must always have the form $f(x) = \frac1{x+u}$ for some constant $u$, so if we want $f(0) = \infty$, we would take $u=0$. My guess is in general, you could convert an equation
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(x) &=& G(x,f(x)) \\
f(0) &=& \infty
\end{eqnarray}
into normal differential equation by substituting $h(x) = 1/f(x)$, which would yield
\begin{eqnarray}
-\frac{h'(x)}{h(x)^2} &=& G\left(x,\frac1{h(x)}\right) \\
h(0) &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
Is this a good approach? My concern is that it the new function $K(x,h) = -h^2 G(x,\frac1h)$ doesn't seem to have any reason to still be Lipschitz continuous, or indeed continuous at all, when $h = 0$. If we perhaps impose a stricter condition on $G$ is the initial value problem with initial value $\infty$ solvable? In general is there some variant of Peano's existence theorem that could be applied to show existence (but possibly not uniqueness) of a solution?

Comment: I actually see some reasons for $K(x,h) = -h^2G(x,1/h)$ to be Lipschitz as well around $h = 0$. Suppose that everything is smooth, which implies $G$ and $\nabla G$ bounded near $h=0$: then $\frac{\partial K}{\partial h} = -2hK(x,1/h) + \frac{\partial G}{\partial f}(x,1/h)$, which is $L^\infty$ (always around $h=0$).

Comment: @Hugo: But the argument of $K$ is $1/h$. If $G$ is not polynomial (or polynomially bounded) of degree at most 2, then $h^2G(x,1/h)$ has a singularity at $h=0$.

Comment: But if you want to pose the problem for "$f(0) = \infty$", then you must assume that $G(x, \cdot)$ is (at least) bounded and continuous in a neighborhood of $\infty$, i.e., $G(x,1/h)$ is bounded when $h$ is close to zero.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily follow. If $f(0) = \infty$ then if $f$ actually makes sense then $f'(0) = G(0,\infty)$ is also infinite, I believe.